# issues with infinite message scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, infinite-scroll

the messages are being loaded properly and everything is fine except that when I load the new messages it goes up straight to the top of the new messages (the older message of the loaded messages) it has to stay on the same level of scrolling and the user should be able to scroll up to see the messages that have been loaded can anyone help this is the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Profile from "./components/Profile";
import ChatLog from "./components/Chat";
import apiService from "../../services/api";
import HttpError from "../../httpError";
import { useLocalStorage } from "usehooks-ts";
import { backendURL, backendWsURL } from "../../../config";
import ChatPanel from "./components/ChatPanel";

const ChatRoom = (props) => {
  const [messageInput, setMessageInput] = useState("");
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);
  const [isAuthReady, setIsAuthReady] = useState(false);
  const [chatMessages, setChatMessages] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [hasNextPage, setHasNextPage] = useState(true);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const chatLog = useRef(null);
  const ws = useRef();
  const [isAuthenticated, saveisAuthenticated] = useLocalStorage("token", null);
  const [userData, setUserData] = useLocalStorage("userData", null);
  const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState(null);
  const chatLogContainerRef = useRef(null);
  const [activeChat, setActiveChat] = useState("");
  const [showupMessage, setShowupMessage] = useState("");
  const [showPanel,setShowPanel] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (activeChat) {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          const getProfile = await apiService.getChatProfile(activeChat);
          setProfileData(getProfile);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error fetching profile data:", error);
        }
      };
      fetchData();
    }
  }, [activeChat]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      setUserName(userData.username);
      setIsReady(true);
    }
  }, [isAuthReady]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isReady || !activeChat) {
      return;
    }

    ws.current = new WebSocket(
      `ws://${backendWsURL}/ws/chat_panel/chat/${activeChat}/?token=${isAuthenticated}`
    );

    ws.current.onopen = () => {
      console.log("Connected to chat socket");
    };

    ws.current.onmessage = (event) => {
      setChatMessages((messages) => [...messages, JSON.parse(event.data)]);
      setShowupMessage(JSON.parse(event.data).content_object.text);
    };

    ws.current.onclose = (event) => {
      if (event.code === 4003) {
        console.log("Error: You are not assigned to this customer.");
      } else {
        console.log("WebSocket connection closed.");
      }
    };
    return () => {
      ws.current.close();
    };
  }, [isReady, activeChat]);

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setMessageInput(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmitf = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission behavior

    if (!messageInput.trim()) {
      return;
    }
    if (
      messageInput &&
      ws.current &&
      ws.current.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN
    ) {
      ws.current.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          message: `${messageInput}`,
          sender_username: `${userName}`,
        })
      );
      setMessageInput("");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollToBottom();
  }, [chatMessages]);

  const scrollToBottom = () => {
    if (chatLogContainerRef.current) {
      const { scrollHeight } = chatLogContainerRef.current;
      chatLogContainerRef.current.scrollTop = scrollHeight;
    }
  };
  const fetchMessages = async () => {
    if (isLoading || !hasNextPage || !activeChat) return;
  
    setIsLoading(true);
    const getMessages = await apiService.fetchMessages({
      roomName: activeChat,
      page: page,
    });
  
    if (!(getMessages instanceof HttpError)) {
      if (getMessages.error) {
        console.log(getMessages.error);
      } else {
        const newMessages = getMessages.messages;
        setChatMessages((prevMessages) => [...newMessages, ...prevMessages]);
        setHasNextPage(getMessages.next_page);
        setPage((prevPage) => prevPage + 1);
      }
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };
  

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isReady) {
      fetchMessages();
    }
  }, [isReady, activeChat]);

  const handleScroll = (event) => {
  const { scrollTop } = event.target;
  if (scrollTop <= 0) {
    // When the user scrolls to the top
    fetchMessages();
  }
};

  const activeChatSetter = (active) => {
    setActiveChat(active);
    setShowPanel(false);
  };
  const setMessageReaded = async () => {
    const readed = await apiService.readMessages(activeChat);
    if (!(readed instanceof HttpError)) {
      if (readed.error) {
        console.log(readed.error);
      } else {
        fetchMessages();
      }
    }
  };
  const toggleShowPanel = ()=>{
      setShowPanel(!showPanel);
  }
  return (
    <div className="flex">
      <ChatPanel
        activeChat={activeChat}
        activeChatSetter={activeChatSetter}
        showupMessage={showupMessage}
        showPanel={showPanel}
      />
      <div className={`flex-1 p:2 sm:p-6 justify-between md:flex flex-col h-[calc(100vh-55px)] md:h-screen shadow-[inset_0_0_4px_rgba(0,0,0,0.6)] ${showPanel && ("hidden")}`}>
        <Profile
          profileData={profileData}
          roomName={activeChat}
          togglePanel={()=>toggleShowPanel()}
        />
        <div
          id="messages"
          className="flex flex-col space-y-4 p-3 h-[73%] overflow-y-auto scrollbar-thumb-blue scrollbar-thumb-rounded scrollbar-track-blue-lighter scrollbar-w-2 scrolling-touch"
          ref={chatLog}
          onScroll={handleScroll}
        >
          <ChatLog
            profileData={profileData}
            chatMessages={chatMessages}
            userName={userName}
            chatLogRef={chatLog}
            onChatLogClick={setMessageReaded}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="border-t-2 border-gray-200 px-4 py-4 sm:mb-0">
          <div className="relative flex">
            <form
              className="message-input-form w-full"
              onSubmit={handleSubmitf}
            >
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Write your message!"
                value={messageInput}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                className="w-full focus:outline-none focus:placeholder-gray-400 text-gray-600 placeholder-gray-600  bg-gray-200 rounded-md py-3"
              />
              <div className="absolute right-0 items-center inset-y-0 hidden sm:flex">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-full h-10 w-10 transition duration-500 ease-in-out text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-300 focus:outline-none"
                >
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    className="h-6 w-6 text-gray-600"
                  >
                    <path
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                      strokeWidth={2}
                      d="M3 9a2 2 0 012-2h.93a2 2 0 001.664-.89l.812-1.22A2 2 0 0110.07 4h3.86a2 2 0 011.664.89l.812 1.22A2 2 0 0018.07 7H19a2 2 0 012 2v9a2 2 0 01-2 2H5a2 2 0 01-2-2V9z"
                    />
                    <path
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                      strokeWidth={2}
                      d="M15 13a3 3 0 11-6 0 3 3 0 016 0z"
                    />
                  </svg>
                </button>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-lg px-4 py-3 transition duration-500 ease-in-out text-white bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-400 focus:outline-none"
                >
                  <span className="font-bold">Send</span>
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                    fill="currentColor"
                    className="h-6 w-6 ml-2 transform rotate-90"
                  >
                    <path d="M10.894 2.553a1 1 0 00-1.788 0l-7 14a1 1 0 001.169 1.409l5-1.429A1 1 0 009 15.571V11a1 1 0 112 0v4.571a1 1 0 00.725.962l5 1.428a1 1 0 001.17-1.408l-7-14z" />
                  </svg>
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChatRoom;
```

Here is a simple example of the issue:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chat Log Example</title>
    <style>
        #chatLog {
            height: 300px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chatLog">
        <!-- ... messages ... -->
    </div>
    <button id="loadMessages">Load Messages</button>

    <script>
        const chatLog = document.getElementById("chatLog");
        const loadMessagesButton = document.getElementById("loadMessages");

        loadMessagesButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                const newMessages = document.createElement("div");
                newMessages.innerText = "New message " + i;

                chatLog.prepend(newMessages);
            }

            chatLog.scrollTop = 0;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please provide some way to replicate this issue like **code-sandbox** or something? By looking at your code I can see two probable issues one with your `scrollToBottom` function and second with `setChatMessages` array

Comment: @mandy8055 I've added a snippet as an example of the issue.

Comment: Are you expecting something like **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/ovptcsfw/)** in react?

Comment: @mandy8055 no I want it to load the messages without showing the newly loaded messages from the top. in another sense, I want to do infinite scroll but scrolling up like a normal chat not down.

Comment: Can you explain this statement of yours in more details please? **when I load the new messages it goes up straight to the top of the new messages (the older message of the loaded messages) it has to stay on the same level of scrolling**